# Using concat in where conditions, good or bad?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, concatenation

### A simple quiz:

Probably many guys know this before,

In my app there is a query in which Im using concat in where condition like this,

v_book_id and v_genre_id are 2 variables in my procedure.

```
SELECT link_id 
FROM link
WHERE concat(book_id,genre_id) = concat(v_book_id,v_genre_id);
```

Now, I know there is a catch/bug in this, which will occur only twice in your lifetime. Can you tell me what is it?

**I found this out yesterday and thought I should make a noise about all others practicing this.**

Thanks.

Comment: Certainly does not help with the indexes.

Comment: if the trailing character of `book_id` can also appear as the leading character of `genre_id` then the combined "key" is not guaranteed unique.  More fool you for picking a dumb way of generating a supposedly unique key.

Comment: @Alnitak : Im working in a place where there are like hundreds of queries using this. Im new here. I have to change all of them now. "If idiots can fly, this place is an airport!!!"

Comment: Agree with Alnitak, for example: using concat wouldn't distinguish following records  
1. Book id = 2. Genre_id = 22, concat = 222;
2. Book id = 22. Genre_id = 2, concat = 222;

Comment: @JA: Then I think you will agree more with Lukas..

Comment: @beck03076: Yes, Wouldn't have bothered commenting if didn't lose 3G connection. Minutes ago. +1 Lukas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's have a look

```
WHERE concat(book_id,genre_id) = concat(v_book_id,v_genre_id);
```

as opposed to

```
WHERE book_id = v_book_id AND genre_id = v_genre_id;
```

There. The second solution is

- faster (optimal index usage)
- easier to write (less code)
- easier to read (what on earth was the author thinking to concatenate numbers???)
- more correct (as [Alnitak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6782/alnitak) also stated in the question's comments). check out this sample data:

  ```
  book_id | genre_id
  1       | 12
  11      |  2
  ```

  Now add (or concat) `v_book_id = 1` and `v_genre_id = 12` and see how you'll get funny results with your `concat()` query

Note, some databases (including MySQL) allow operations on *tuples*, which may be what the clever author of the above really intended to do:

```
WHERE (book_id, genre_id) = (v_book_id, v_genre_id);
```

A working example of such a tuple predicate:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 1 x, 2 y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 x, 3 y FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 x, 2 y FROM DUAL 
) a
WHERE (x, y) = (1, 2)
```

Note, some databases will need extra parentheses around the right-hand side tuple : `((1, 2))`

Comment: Thats right and this is even more right. "if the trailing character of book_id can also appear as the leading character of genre_id then the combined "key" is not guaranteed unique. More fool you for picking a dumb way of generating a supposedly unique key.".. Kudo to Alnitak.

Comment: yup, that last point is the one I made in my comment in the "question".

Comment: @Alnitak: Nice, I didn't see that comment. I'll give you credit

Comment: Im waiting to accept yours as the right answer!! 2 more minutes!!